# plot chart with multidimentional arrAY data in js

Tags: javascript, arrays, charts

my data is in the form of multidimentional array
somthing like this

```
v[][]=[ [122,null,123,null,null,234,null,434],
        [null,453,null,null,123,null,123,null],
        [null,null,null,123,null,null,null,null]
      ];
```

**here the array size is changed dynamically**

how should i plot data outta it with x axis of time i was using chart.js but i countnot plot over my html webpage please correct me if i am wrong or suggest any alternative way please.

```
function chartInit(a,b,c){
var config = {
            type: 'line',
            label: c,
            data: {
                labels: b,
                datasets: [{
                    label: 'data',
                    backgroundColor: window.chartColors.orange,
                    borderColor: window.chartColors.orange,
                         borderWidth: 1,
//                      stacking: normal,
                         data: a,
                    fill: false,
}]
            },
            options: {
             spanGaps: true,
                display: true,
                responsive: true,
                title: {
                    display: true,
                    text: x
                },
                tooltips: {
                    mode: 'index',
                    intersect: false,
                },
                hover: {
                    mode: 'nearest',
                    intersect: true
                },
                scales: {
                    xAxes: [{
        //        type: 'time',
      //          time: {
    //               unit: 'second'
  //              }
                stacked: true,
               display: true,
                       scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'Timestamp'
                        }
   }],

                         yAxes: [{
                        display: true,
                        scaleLabel: {
                            display: true,
                            labelString: 'time'
                        }
//                      stacked: true
                    }]
                }
            }
        };
        return config
        }
```

```
for(var i=0;i<array.size;i++){
window.myLine6 = new Chart(ctx,chartInit(v[i], timearray, array[i]));
myLine6.destroy();
}
}
```

i tried like this but this is not what i wanted i want the array v[][] in one  chart

Comment: Can you please post the code? So we can know what chart are you plotting what data are you passing etc

Comment: please check i have updated